# Problem when using writer_pdf_Export filter in UNO LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice, uno

I installed LibreOffice [LibreOffice 6.1.3.2 10(Build:2)] and sdk on Ubuntu 16.03.

I used the java sample DocumentConverter in the sdk package to convert an odt in different formats.

With "MS WORD 97" or "Text" there is no problem but with "writer_pdf_Export" it ends in Exception

OK

```
java -jar /home/js/libreoffice6.1_sdk/LINUXexample.out/class/JavaDocumentHandlingExamples/DocumentConverter.jar "./test" "MS WORD 97" "doc" "/home/js/libreoffice6.1_sdk/LINUXexample.out/misc/JavaDocumentHandlingExamples/converted_files"
Connected to a running office ...

The converted documents will stored in "/home/js/libreoffice6.1_sdk/LINUXexample.out/misc/JavaDocumentHandlingExamples/converted_files!
[test]
   test1.odt
```

KO

```
java -jar /home/js/libreoffice6.1_sdk/LINUXexample.out/class/JavaDocumentHandlingExamples/DocumentConverter.jar "./test" "writer_pdf_Export" "pdf" "/home/js/libreoffice6.1_sdk/LINUXexample.out/misc/JavaDocumentHandlingExamples/converted_files"
Connected to a running office ...

The converted documents will stored in "/home/js/libreoffice6.1_sdk/LINUXexample.out/misc/JavaDocumentHandlingExamples/converted_files!
[test]
com.sun.star.task.ErrorCodeIOException: SfxBaseModel::impl_store <file:////home/js/libreoffice6.1_sdk/LINUXexample.out/misc/JavaDocumentHandlingExamples/converted_files/test1.pdf> failed: 0x81a(Error Area:Io Class:Parameter Code:26)
    at   com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.Job.remoteUnoRequestRaisedException(Job.java:158)
    at com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.Job.execute(Job.java:122)
    at com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.JobQueue.enter(JobQueue.java:312)
    at com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.JobQueue.enter(JobQueue.java:281)
    at com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.JavaThreadPool.enter(JavaThreadPool.java:81)
    at com.sun.star.lib.uno.bridges.java_remote.java_remote_bridge.sendRequest(java_remote_bridge.java:618)
    at com.sun.star.lib.uno.bridges.java_remote.ProxyFactory$Handler.request(ProxyFactory.java:145)
    at com.sun.star.lib.uno.bridges.java_remote.ProxyFactory$Handler.invoke(ProxyFactory.java:129)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.storeAsURL(Unknown Source)
    at DocumentConverter.traverse(DocumentConverter.java:137)
    at DocumentConverter.main(DocumentConverter.java:216)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.star.lib.loader.Loader.main(Loader.java:132)
  test1.odt
```

I need to use the UNO interface through java to convert to any format, and I really need pdf also...
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing "storeAsURL" or "storeToURL"?

"storeAsURL" is analogous to "Save As" -- for when you are saving a document in an editable format.

"storeToURL" is analogous to "Export" -- for generating an output in an uneditable format.

So I suspect that, if you switch from "storeAsURL" to "storeToURL", you'll get the PDF you wanted.

Comment: Not the OP, but I have the same issue and this doesn't fix it for me unfortunately.

Comment: same. this didnt work for me either. Getting the same error